# c++ on mac / eclipse does not show error when crashing

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, debugging

Hi I am working with a fresh installation of c++ / eclipse. I am using Cross GCC and my all options look like

```
-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -v
```

When ever the application crashes, as I am refreshing myself on c++, it just exits nicely, no stack trace, no Hey you had a seg fault message. NOTHING. It is not usable to not get an error output saying where a crash was.

What simple step or flag am I missing?

An example where I write way out of bounds.

```
cout << "this will crash! " << endl;
int foo[1000];
for (int i = 0; i <= 3000 ; i++)
    foo[i] = i;
cout << "!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
```

Output

```
this will crash!
```

And nothing else.

Thanks!
Oh I am running GDB for the debugger. The debugger works as far as break points and such.

Comment: Have you tried running it in `gdb` from the command line instead to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's compiling with -O0?

When I compile this code with -O2, the compiler detects that initialising the array has no external side-effects or dependencies and completely elides it.

```
.LC0:
        .string "this will crash! "
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $17, %edx
        movl    $.LC0, %esi
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    std::__ioinit, %edi
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init()
        movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
        movl    std::__ioinit, %esi
        movl    std::ios_base::Init::~Init(), %edi
        addq    $8, %rsp
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```